# Cant declare variable SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, declare

I've been trying to declare an integer variable but its just not working. Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @count INT
SET     @count = 5633

SELECT count(matchid) 
FROM   `matches`
WHERE   id = @count
```

Im getting this error:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @count INT
SET     @count = 5633
```

Please help :)

Comment: Remember to **accept** the answer you found most useful. Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 7):

According to the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/declare.html), DECLARE is only allowed inside a BEGIN ... END block, and must be at the start. You're also forgetting a semicolon on the end of each line. This should work for you:

```
SET @count = 5633;

SELECT count(*) 
FROM matches
WHERE id = @count;
```

`COUNT(*)` is faster in some cases.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` may be faster but it is not the same as `COUNT(matchid)` (I mean, in general).

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @count INT;
SET     @count = 5633;

SELECT count(matchid) 
FROM   matches
WHERE   id = @count;
```

Also, you apparently [need](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html) a begin/end block.

Comment: That still doesnt work for some reason. Its telling me there is an SQL syntax error near 'DECLARE @count INT'

Comment: As @Dave shows above, you need to end your statements with a semicolon `;` and I don't think you need to DECLARE.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it all in-line

```
SELECT
      count(matchid) 
   FROM   
      `matches`,
      ( select @count := 5633 ) SQLVars
   WHERE   
      matches.id = @count
```

but more direct would otherwise, just have it directly in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @count INT
SET     @count = 5633

SELECT count(matchid) 
FROM    matches  //<===  should be table name
WHERE   id = @count
```

Comment: @JamesStevenson you are wrong. look at the answer . Ive just tested it and you had another error with the `'matches'`. Ive fixed it also.

Comment: No that bit works fine, because this query works SELECT count(matchid) 
FROM   `matches`
WHERE  id = 5633 The problem is with the declaring of the variable not the table